# Android: Cannot get a clickable ListView header/footer

Tags: java, android, listview, header, onclick

I'm trying to set a header and footer in my list view that are clickable buttons. The problem is that the OnClickListener isn't responding to anything and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
$   View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_layout, null, true);
    getListView().addHeaderView(header);

    myAdapter = new myAdapter(this);

    header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do what I want when i click it
        }
    });
```

**Update**
The best solution I ultimately came up with was adding a separate button to the header layout, and then doing it like this:

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_layout, null);
Button headerButton = (Button)header.findViewById(R.id.header_button);
getListView().addHeaderView(header);

headerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     // My Click Stuff
     }
});
```

Comment: You might have missed this line `header.setClickable(true)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a few issues:

- when inflating the header, use getListView() as the second parameter (root, where you have null now)l
- should the header be a View or a ViewGroup?  I've ended up using ViewGroup in these situations.
- finally -- perhaps you should be setting the click listener on the button in the header instead of the header itself?

Comment: Third bullet fixed it, also ensuring to use the header view when creating the button. It's closer to what i was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

You need to handle the click in the `ListView`'s `onItemClick`. Simply check if that's the first or last item in the `adapter` and handle the clicks that way. You need to treat it as an item in the `ListView`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way more easier solution:

Just set a "OnClickListener" to the applied View:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxx, null);
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Very easy thing which solved it!

Answer (score 2):

Example with a footer:

```
mYourListView.addFooterView(footer, null, true);
```

Then in the OnItemClickListener you can check:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View view, final int position, final long id) {

    if (id != -1) {
        // do whatever you do with list items
    } else {
        // do what you need after the footer been clicked
    }
```

(If you need to handle and the header and the footer click, check position - 0 for the header and [adapter.getCount() - 1] for the footer)

This approach will provide the same visual effect while footer click as if the list item been clicked. (But if you do not need that effect just add OnClickListener to the footer and it will intercept all footer clicks)

Answer (score 0):

i think the listview and buttons are fighting for focus and your listview is winning.
you'll have to use a onTouchListener for the buttons.

There is one more alternative and its to set the following on the footer.  There is another method overload created but it did not come up in the docs, i had to check online documentation:

mylistView.addFooterView(footerView, null, **false**);

where false tells the footer its not selectable.  I tested this myself and the buttons inside the footer respond to touches now.  I hope this an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

When inflating the header view, before adding it to the listview, I then used that view to get the subview and add a click listener on it

```
myHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.myButton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ... } );
```

also, when I added it to the listView, I used the overloaded constructor with the third variable set to `true`

```
mListView.addHeaderView(myHeaderView, null, true);
```